# sum of two continous fucntions is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I know how to prove this for the usual metric $|x-y|$ but say I'm given a metric space $(X,d)$ and real continuous functions on X $f,g$ does it still hold that $f+g$ and $fg$ are continuous on$X$? I'm assuming it does, but when we defined continuity we said supposed we had two metric spaces: $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ and $f: X \to Y$ is continuous if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $d_X(x,y) < \delta \implies d_Y(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$. but in the example I gave, what is $d_Y$? how is continuity defined in that example?

Comment: Theorems related to the convergence of sequences are very useful here.

Comment: I'm not asking how exactly to prove the statement, rather what is the definition of continuity in this given case?

Comment: Well, continuity has the same meaning everywhere. $d_X$ and $d_Y$ are what you define them. $d_Y$ might be anything: usual metric, discrete metric, etc.

Comment: I understand where your confusion comes from. Actually, we can't just say "f is continuos on X", we need to specify from where and TO where f is continuous.

Comment: yes I agree, but that's all the question says that's why I was confused :(

Comment: What's the full statement of the question?

Comment: let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $f,g$ be continuous real functions on $X$. Show $f+g$ is continuous on X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f : (X,d_X) \to (Y,d_Y)$ is continuous if to every $\epsilon > 0$ and $c\in X$, there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x\in X$, $d_X(x,c) < \delta$ implies $d_Y(f(x),f(c)) < \epsilon$. Usually, to say that $f$ is a continuous real function on $X$ means that $f : X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, where $\Bbb R$ is given the standard metric.

Comment: yes i agree, i'm saying that if I'm given a metric space $(X,d)$ and two real continuous functions $f,g$ on $X$ what does it mean to say that $f$ is continuous on $X$? What is $d_Y$?

Comment: $d_Y$ is the metric on $Y$.

Comment: yes but in the case I gave we have no "$Y$"...

Comment: So you're talking about a continuous function from $(X,d_X)$ to $\Bbb R$ with the standard metric, right?

Comment: if it was that then I understand, but the question specifically says "$f$ is a real continous function on X" if it was the real line it'd make sense

Comment: But that's what it means.

Comment: *how* does it mean that?

Comment: By "real" they mean real-valued. So a real continuous function is a real-valued continuous function.

Comment: alright, that makes sense then. Thanks.